# Entity Framework lazy loading in using statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I am so curious, when I went to deep into Entity Framework and will be glad to help me understand about lazy loading in this example which I show here:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PersonID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StoreID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Territory Territory { get; set; }
}

public partial class Territory
{
    public Territory()
    {
        this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    public int TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }
    public string C_Group_ { get; set; }
    public decimal SalesYTD { get; set; }
    public decimal SalesLastYear { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult LoadData()
{
    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
    var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
    var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

    var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

    var pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    var skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    int totalRecords = 0;

    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {           
        //1.
        var items = dc.Customers.Select(a => a);

        //2. 
        //var items = dc.Customers.Select(a => new
        //{
        //    a.CustomerID,
        //    a.PersonID,
        //    a.StoreID,
        //    TerritoryName = a.Territory.Name,
        //    a.AccountNumber,
        //    a.ModifiedDate
        //});

        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
        {
            items = items.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
        }

        totalRecords = items.Count();
        var data = items.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        return Json(new { recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsToral = totalRecords, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I've numbered some parts. In first case as you see I select all customers, lazy loading is true and this throws an error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

If I uncomment the second part, it will work without errors. The only difference between them is that in second case I select columns which I need

Comment: I would say that you don't need `Select(a => a)` in the first case.

Comment: Also what is `items.OrderBy` here? OrderBy doesn't take a string as a parameter, it takes a func or more usually an expression.

Comment: @DavidG I thought It would be understandable beacouse of I did not write whole code, I recorected it, you can check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `JsonResult`(from `return Json(...)` statement) will be executed by ASP after the `using` block is left and it will try to serialize all fields of your `Customer` object and will try to reach `Territory` reference property after your dbcontext has been disposed.

Comment: But in second case, I also make reference to Territory field in select statement and it works. Why?

Comment: @www1986, yes, there is no laziness in second case, cause you fetch value `TerritoryName = a.Territory.Name` before leaving the using block. So in first case `Territory` is lazily evaluated during result execution after your action returns(and dbcontext is disposed), in second case dbcontext is not present during result execution, you have executed your request to database(`items.Count()` and `items.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList()`) and your are working with anonymous type, which has all the data already fetched.

Comment: Thank you and I add that with eager loading would be the same error too, am I right?

Comment: @www1986, no, if you add `eager loading` in first case (like `items = dc.Customers.Include(a => a.Territory)`) it should not fail, but if you will add something for `lazy loading` in the second case it will fail too(you can try to add something like `Terr = a.Territory,` to your select statement in second case, since `Territory` has navigation property `Customers` it should fail)

Comment: I turn off Lazyloading and add eager loading:  dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; dc.Customers.include("Territory").Select(a=>a) and now it throws another error: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Customer_8DC93F325445353'.

Comment: @www1986 Yes, because your object is serialized to json, and your `Customer` has reference to a `Territory` which in turn has reference to the customer itself(because it ), so serializer throws this error. You can try to mark `Territory.Customers` property with ignore attribute(i think `ScriptIgnoreAttribute` should do it, but i'm not sure) and the property will not be serialized, so the error should go away

Comment: yes, you are right, it works with this attribute [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]. I so harassed you, but one more question :) . I wrote this 2 query: 1. dc.Customers.Where(w => w.CustomerID == 10).SingleOrDefault().Territory; 2. dc.Customers.Where(w => w.CustomerID == 10).Select(s => s.Territory); First I run it with Lazyloading turned on an both of them works. But when I turned off Lazyloading first query returns null, Territory property is null and in second query Territory Property was filled with corresponding data.

Comment: @www1986, no problem) Yes in first case it will return null for `Territory` without lazy loading cause it is not fetched from db in you query(you can use profiler to see what query is executed on your db), it will work if you add `.Include(w => w.Territory)`. In second one you are explicitly tell that you need `Territory` in your select clause, so it is fetched from db. [Here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/06/what-is-eager-loading-and-what-is-lazy.html) you can see a small explanation.